# How to print a string one word at a time, on one line with all of the string visible. - Python

Tags: python, string, repeat

I want to make the word: 'error' repeat itself numerous times. This is an easy task in itself, but I do not know how to print them one at a time, at whatever speed I choose. I understand that my question has been partially covered, but I do  not wish for the previous word of the string to dissapear.

```
 print('Error! ' *20)
```

The output that I want is Error! Error! (each released individually instead of being released all at once.)

How can I make it so that python does not release all of the string at the same time? It would also be good to know whether I can make it print in columns, but still along the widths.

Comment: Could you show an example of the output you are expecting? It's unclear what you want from your question.

Comment: Your code raises an error.

Comment: `print("error !",end=""); time.sleep(1)` loop on that?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I though that to, but he also said: _"How can I make it so that python does not release all of the string at the same time?"_ which seems to indicate he wants to iterate over each character.

Comment: in that case it's a duplicate. but I already closed because unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print `Error!` 20 times (on 20 lines/rows), over a duration of 20 seconds

```
import time

for _ in range(20):
    print("Error!")
    time.sleep(1)  # change 1 to whatever number you want, to control the amount of time before "Error!" is printed again
```

This will print "Error!" 20 times on the same line (20 columns) over a duration of 20 seconds:

```
import time

for _ in range(20):
    print("Error!", end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)  # change 1 to whatever number you want, to control the amount of time before "Error!" is printed again
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
for _ in range(20):
    print('Error!', end=' ', flush=True) # flush courtesy inspectorG4dget to disable buffering
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

This'll print 'Error!' every 200 milliseconds on the same line (...20 times). Change that `for` to a `while` for better control over the stopping condition.

Comment: Use `flush=True` inside `print` so that it prints incrementally

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yep... forgot the output'll be buffered.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
for i in range(20):
    print ("Error!")
    time.sleep(60) #pause for one minute
```

You can use a for loop to choose the number of times to print, and `sleep()` from the time library to do the pausing.